# Magento 1.9 (PayPal) Proxy Authentification

Tags: magento, curl, paypal, proxy

We have a "Magento 1.9.2.1 CE" based web shop.
We have activated PayPal as payment option, where PayPal API uses Proxy. In Magento Backend we are able to enter Host and Port for our Proxy. The Problem is that our Proxy does not get authenticated.
Where can I add a username and password to authenticate?

Could somebody please give me some more info on how to make Magento PayPal to connect itself via Proxy and to authenticate.

Comment: Where exactly do you have issues authenticating? On you proxy or on your Paypal account?

Comment: Tnx John, on my Proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not the proxy authentication but the length of the response we got from PayPal. Response is usually an array of 2 elements. But when the communication goes through Proxy, this array has 4 elements.

We had to rewrite Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp and update the call($methodName, array $request) function.
There we replaced

```
$response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 2);
$response = trim($response[1]);
```

with

```
$response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 4);
$response = trim($response[3]);
```

This solved our problem. So there was no need of adding a proxy password to the Magento.